# category O is semisimple

Tags: rt.representation-theory, kac-moody-algebras

I have been reading the book "Automorphic forms and Lie superalgebras". In Section 2.6, Definition 2.6.15 we have the definition of Category O for BKM Lie superalgebras (I have also checked the book infinite-dimensional Lie algebras by Minoru Wakimato). I am interested to know, whether this category (or integrable modules in this category) is completely reducible or not?

I know this is true for BKM algebras from this paper : 
 Kyeonghoon Jeong, Seok-Jin Kang and  Masaki Kashiwara.
Crystal bases for quantum generalized Kac-Moody algebras. Proc. Lond. Math. Soc. 90(3), no. 2, 395--438, 2005.  but I couldn't guess or prove for the case of BKM superalgebras.

Kindly help me with this and suggest me some references. Thanking you.